# How to apply custom validation in vue-tel-input

Tags: regex, vue.js, vue-tel-input

As the title says, what is the process to applying a `customValidate` regex in vue-tel-input? You can see `customValidate` as the last item in the list of [props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input#props). I have a standard setup like in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-tel-input-playground-wznqo). However, when I add a regex for the phone number to only allow a phone number with digits and a starting "+", the code hangs and kills my browser, `customValidate: /^\+\d+$/`. Is my formatting correct or is there another approach I should take? Is my regex ok?

Comment: facing same, did you find a solution?